# OrderedDictionary C# Как получить значения последней пары?

Tags: c#

Требуется получить значения последней добавленной пары в словарь. Знаю, что стандартная `Dictionary` не позволяет этого сделать. Для подобных целей вроде бы используют `OrderedDictionary`. Как получить значения последней добавленной пары `<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: `OrderedDictionary` тоже не про это, используйте стэк, например

Comment: Название не очень соответствует описанию. Если вам нужно значение последней пары, используйте свойство ```Count - 1```. Если вам нужно значение последней ***добавленной*** пары, запоминайте его сами в своем коде, такое словарь не умеет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Расширьте класс и сделайте словарь под нужды. Это не запрещено и не противоречит solid

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LastOrderedDictionary myOrderedDictionary = new LastOrderedDictionary();

        myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey1", "testValue1");
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey2", "testValue2");
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("keyToDelete", "valueToDelete");
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey3", "testValue3");

        Console.Out.WriteLine($"key = {myOrderedDictionary.LastKey.ToString()}," +
            $" value ={myOrderedDictionary.LastValue.ToString()}");

    }
}

public class LastOrderedDictionary : OrderedDictionary
{

    public new void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        this.LastKey = key;
        this.LastValue = value;
    }

    public Object LastKey
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public Object LastValue
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```